# How to get the value of data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html, dom

I am working on a node.js application which generates a html page. This html page displays a list of associates built according to the data passed onto this page. A list is built something like as follows:

```
<ul class="notification-body" style="">
    //loop for all assocaite id's passed to this page
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="<%= assocID %>">
         <span>
             <span class="subject">
                  <label class="btnClass label label-info">ClickMe!</label>
             </span>
         </span>
    </li>
```

The generated html src looks something like this:

```
<ul class="notification-body" style="">
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA01">
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA02">
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA03">
```

I am trying to get the value of the data attribute using Jquery & I tried the following:

```
   $(".btnClass").click(function(){
        console.log($".testClass").attr("data-associateid"));
   });
```

But this outputs'AA01'everytime i click on the btn and I am not getting the expected output in the console:
AA01
AA02
AA03

I tried the following also but it gives me undefined:

```
   $(".btnClass").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).find(".testClass").attr("data-associateid"));
   });
```

Comment: Where is the element with class `.btnClass` in your html code?

Comment: I think you need to look into this: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: sorry guys i have updated the code in the original post

Comment: From jquery: The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

Comment: Updated my answer to match what you are asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `jQuery.data()`.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u27jse4t/) to show this working.

I've closed the `LI` because AR.

```
<ul class="notification-body" style="">
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA01">1</li>
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA02">2</li>
    <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA03">3</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testClass').on('click', function(){
        alert( $(this).data('associateid') );
    });
});
```

Anytime you have an attribute that starts with `data-`, you can reference the string after the dash as a data container. Here, I'm calling `jQuery.data()` on an object (the LI) and asking for the data in the container `associateID`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are currently doing:

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){
     console.log($(".testClass").attr("data-associateid"));
});
```

Will match the first instance of `.testClass` and print the `data-associateid` attribute. What you seem to want to do is to iterate over all `.testClass` and print their `data-associateid` values:

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){
     $(".testClass").each(function() {
       console.log($(this).attr('data-associateid'));
     });
});
```

Based on your updated HTML you would do this:

```
$(".btnClass").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parents('.testClass').attr('data-associateid');
    console.log(id);
});
```

This will search the parents of the clicked on `.btnClass` to find elements with the class `.testClass`.

Comment: Provided detailed solution, downvoter should care to explaing the action of downV's ....+1 for help

Answer (score 2):

To get the data for that instance you simply need to traverse to the parent `<li>`.

Within an event handler, `this` is the element that the event occured on. Use `closest()` to access the parent `<li>`

```
$(".btnClass").on('click', function(){
        alert( $(this).closest('li').data('associateid') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign different classes to your li elements like this:

```
<ul class="notification-body" style="">
    <li class="testClass1" data-associateid="AA01">test 1</li>
    <li class="testClass2" data-associateid="AA02">test 2</li>
    <li class="testClass3" data-associateid="AA03">test 2</li>
</ul>
```

Note, that I closed your li and ul tags to have valid HTML.

And then you can select an element with its own class:

```
console.log($(".testClass2").attr("data-associateid"));
```

I created a JSFiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rLpbk5m/

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that you want to log all IDs. So it's Jonathan Crowe's answer.

Comment: assigning unique classes isn't necessary or very scalable. Numerous other ways to access an element

Answer (score 1):

I had hoped you could do it with just a find but apparently not. You have to use each to loop through all the elements.

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){
   $(".testClass").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-associateid'));
  });
});
```

View it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rt677qp5/

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your responses. I have updated the html structure i am using in the original post. So basically, when i click on the label 'clickMe' I want to console.log() the value of the corresponsing assocaiteId for that <li>

Answer (score 1):

Using .data() is more logical in this case.

```js
$(".btnClass").click(function() {
  $(".testClass").each(function() {

    alert($(this).data("associateid"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="notification-body" style="">
  <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA01"></li>
  <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA02"></li>
  <li class="testClass" data-associateid="AA03"></li>
</ul>
<button class="btnClass"></button>
```